# problem with taking piece of text from lineEdit in Dialog into lineEdit @ mainwindow

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

im quite new to Qt and trying to do this simple thing, but i cant:(
here is what i want to do on the picture : http://pokazywarka.pl/r2dwtb-2/

thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt - Radiobutton in diff dialog(window) -> taking result to the mainwindow into lineedit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866930/qt-radiobutton-in-diff-dialogwindow-taking-result-to-the-mainwindow-into-l)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a straight-forward setText;

```
ui->lineEdit2->setText( ui->lineEdit1->text() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it "automaticly" by connecting signal textChanged to slot setText

```
connect(ui.lineEdit1, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), ui2.lineEdit2, SLOT(setText(const QString &)));
```